# MongoDB udate query using class object in C#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am storing class object in mongodb like below,

```
try
{
    Sample risk = new Sample();
    risk.Name = "ABC";
    risk.Enable = true;
    risk.Sender = "IBM";
    risk.Target = "CITI";
    MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost");
    MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("DATABASE");
    db.GetCollection<StockQuote>("SMAPLETABLE").Insert(risk);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

now i want to to update that same class instance like   `db.GetCollection<StockQuote>("SMAPLETABLE").Insert(risk);` how can i do this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two approaches two update document:

1.Via `Save` method and update etire document

```
db.GetCollection<StockQuote>("SMAPLETABLE").Save(risk);
```

2.Via [atomic update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations): update part of document. For example if you need update `Enable` field of document with `Name`  "`ABC`":

```
db.GetCollection<StockQuote>("SMAPLETABLE").Update(
                                        Query.EQ("Name", "ABC"),
                                        Update.Set("Enable", false));
```

Some notes:

1. With atomic updates you can avoid concurrency issues. Atomic update it is like transaction within one document.

Comment: if i am using SAVE method, id mongo table have 4 records, how can i update particular record only.@Andrew Orsich

Comment: @user483886: when you using `Save` you actually updating single document. _id field is unique across entire collection.

Comment: But how i know that particular document when updating, if there mention that id....?@Andrew Orsich

Comment: can u send one sample code for update entire documnet at a time @Andrew Orsich

Comment: To update entire document you need load it from database first. You can use `FindOneAs<>` for example: `db.GetCollection<StockQuote>("SMAPLETABLE").FindOneAs<StockQuote>(Query.EQ("Name", "ABC"));`